# Postgresql / split one record on two rows depending of two fields

Tags: postgresql

Depending of this `users` table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE users
AS
  SELECT id,name,email1,email2
  FROM ( VALUES 
    ( 1, 'John', 'john@doe.com', 'foo@bar.com' ),
    ( 2, 'Baz' , 'baz@bar.com' , null )
  ) AS t(id,name,email1,email2);
```

Is it possible to have this output with one query ?

```
John | john@doe.com
John | foo@bar.com
Baz  | baz@bar.com
```

Comment: Conditional expressions in SQL?

Comment: @MladenUzelac Sure, but how should I output 2 distinct rows if for one record both `email` and `email2` are provided ?

Comment: @ceandreak using set operation UNION maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Mladen's answer you can also use `LATERAL` to transpose columns to rows:

```
select t.name, t.email
from users u
cross join LATERAL ( values ( u.name, u.email1 )
                          , ( u.name, u.email2 ) ) as t
```

`LATERAL` makes it possible to reference tables at the same level that are declared above, so we can create a virtual table with two rows in terms of users.

`LATERAL` can be beneficial performancewise compared to `UNION`

Comment: I think the performance would be substantially detrimental under all workloads. LATERAL isn't exactly fast.

Comment: test: `CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT x::int AS x1, trunc(x*3/7)::int AS x2 FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS t(x);` q1: `SELECT x1 FROM foo UNION ALL SELECT x2 FROM foo;` q2: `SELECT x FROM foo CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( VALUES (x1),(x2) ) AS t(x);` q2 is twice as slow as q1.

Comment: I haven't used LATERAL with Postgresql but for DB2 the number of rows read is usually significantly reduced. In a case like this it probably does not matter at all so I just mentioned it as a side note.

Comment: I could not edit my comment so I'll add a new one. I did a similar test for DB2 as yours,  and the time to execute the queries where about the same. The estimated cost for the LATERAL query where about 60% of the UNION query and the number of I/O:s where also reduced to about half.

Comment: I confirm, the fasted (~50% compared to `UNION`) is `LATERAL`, in my case. Thanks for this addition

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, email FROM users
UNION
SELECT name, email2 FROM users;
```

email and email2 have to be of the same type

Comment: So simple, thanks but not elegant if a where clause is added. But it does the job

Comment: @ceadreak not really. just wrap the thing in another select.

Comment: Also this should be `UNION ALL` or it'll be slower and you'll be eliminating duplicates. Like if Bob's email2, is Sally's email1. Or, if two users have the same email address.